# Is it possible to iterate over imported modules in javascript?

Tags: javascript, module

I have a common exported property, route, in all my imported modules that I would like to access dynamically, but can't work out how to iterate over the list of imported modules. Can this be done?

```
import User from '/components/user.js';
import Document from '/components/document.js';

var routes = [];
[array of imported modules].forEach(m => routes.push(m.route));
```

UPDATE:

So far I've tried the following and can't find the module list on any of them

```
console.log(User.constructor);
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(this));
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(User));
```

Where should I be looking?

Comment: Do you want something dynamic ? Otherwise you could just do `[User, Document]`

Comment: Yes. The list of imports is quite long, so I preferably don't want to have to remember to add in another reference.

Comment: Did you try it and see? What happened? You won't break anything if you mess around attempting it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing that which I can think of would involve using eval(), as there are no dynamic import statements right now in js.

I would suggest using a different library perhaps? Take a look here:
https://github.com/jojois74/recycle.js

Simply save the object that you pass to mod.prepare, and then iterate over its keys.